# Asp.NET Core with Json file in root

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I want to add this string (jsonValue)to json file in root

```
  var JsonValue = JsvalueonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsonValue);` to add json string to a json file(here is `myData.json`)

Use `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` to get root path or write your path manually.

For example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //other logic
        var jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);

        //get your own path
        string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        string path = Path.Combine(contentRootPath, "myData.json");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsonValue);
    }
}
```